# Form submission determiend on Ajax response

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms

There's a form users fill out and click the submit button. The data gets sent back to the server and based on the servers server's response the form is submitted or not (and the page is redirected or not). The problem is the form always submits and the page redirects before the server's response is received.

```
        function SubmitForm(name, data1)
        {
            var result;
            var checkResult = function(result)
            {
                alert("final value is: "+result)
                return result
            }
            var xmlhttp
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
            {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            else
            {// code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
            {
                if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
                {
                    if(xmlhttp.responseText)
                    {
                        result = true
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        document.getElementById("report").innerHTML = "blah blah blah"
                        result = false
                    }
                    checkResult(result)
                }
            }
            xmlhttp.open("POST", "Checkdata1.php", true);
            xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
            xmlhttp.send("name="+encodeURIComponent(name.value)+"&data1="+encodeURIComponent(data1.value))
            //return false
        }
```

Here's the HTML for the form that calls the above JavaScript function.

```
<form onsubmit="return isPasswordCorrect(document.getElementById('name'), document.getElementById('txtField1'))" action="nextpage.php" method="GET">
```

I know the idea is for the function to return `false` to prevent the form from being submitted, but how do I get it to wait long enough for the server to reply through Ajax? By the way, I haven't needed JQuery and if it's not necessary I'd prefer not to start using it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a `<button>` that doesn't submit the form (the type isn't `"submit"`):

```
<form ...>
...
<button onclick="SubmitForm(...)">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Then at the end of `SubmitForm`, you can put:

```
document.querySelector("form").submit();
```

When you want to submit the form.